# How to replace item while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change navbar when scrolling a page. How to catch the moment when to change it? How to do it right, in accordance with the concepts of React?  As far as I know, use getElementById is that bad tone?

```
const useState = React.useState
const useEffect = React.useEffect

const Component = () => {
    const [topNavbarHide, setTopNavbarHide] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            let navbarSize = document.getElementById('navbar').offsetHeight;
            console.log("navbarSize " + navbarSize + "px");
            let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            console.log("scrollTop " + scrollTop);
            if (scrollTop > navbarSize) {
                setTopNavbarHide(false)
            } else {
                setTopNavbarHide(true)
            }
            console.log(topNavbarHide);
        });
    });


    return (
        <div>
            <div id={"navbar"} className="navbar">
                <div
                    className={(topNavbarHide) ? "topNavbar" : "topNavbar hide"}>topNavbar
                </div>
                <div className="bottomNavbar">bottomNavbar</div>
            </div>
            <div className="box"></div>
            <div className="box1"></div>
            <div className="box2"></div>
            <div className="box"></div>
            <div className="box1"></div>
        </div>
    )

};


ReactDOM.render(
    <Component/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

https://codepen.io/slava4ka/pen/wvvGoBX

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to add an event listener, in the way that you are currently doing it, to a React hook. The way that you are doing it is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

There is another, more simpler way with react-waypoint. You can place invisible waypoints on your screen and it can trigger events when waypoint enter or leave screen.

For example:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [topNavbarHide, setTopNavbarHide] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id={"navbar"} className="navbar">
        <div className={topNavbarHide ? "topNavbar" : "topNavbar hide"}>
          topNavbar
        </div>
        <div className="bottomNavbar">bottomNavbar</div>
      </div>
      <Waypoint 
        onEnter={() => setTopNavbarHide(true)} 
        onLeave={() => setTopNavbarHide(false)}
      />
      <div className="box" />
      <div className="box1" />
      <div className="box2" />
      <div className="box" />
      <div className="box1" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

It is basically working like your example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-hodgkin-5jucl